# 'OBJECT' not declared in scope

Tags: c++

My first ever c++ program and i cant seem to figure out why it says that my 'object' was not declared in the scope. I've included the header files, i've prototyped my functions.  i'm used to coding in java and the separation is pretty confusing to me.

The aim of the program is simple: create a class: Semester.

Semester: will have ID, name, credit, marks.

provide get/set methods to input and output from kb

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Semester.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Semester s1;
  cout << "Please enter ID" << endl;
  cin >> sl.setid();
  cout << "ID: " << s1.getid();
}
```

cpp

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Semester.h"

 using namespace std;

 Semester::Semester(){

 }

 //setters
void Semester::setid(string t_id) {id = t_id;}
void Semester::setunit(string t_name) {unit_name = t_name;}
void Semester::setcredit(int t_credit){credit = t_credit;}
void Semester::setmark(int t_marks) {marks = t_marks;}

//getters
string Semester::getid() {return id;}
string Semester::getunit() {return unit_name;}
int Semester::getcredit() {return credit;}
int Semester::getmark() {return marks;}
```

header

```
#ifndef SEMESTER_H
#define SEMESTER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


class Semester{
   private: //variables
   std::string id;
   std:: string unit_name;
   int credit, marks;

   public:
   Semester(); //constructor
   //setters
   void setid(std::string id);
   void setunit(std::string name);
   void setcredit(int credit);
   void setmark(int marks);

   //getters
   std::string getid();
   std::string getunit();
   int getcredit();
   int getmark();
};
 #endif // SEMESTER_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is incorrect.

```
cin >> sl.setid();
```

Problems with that line:

1. You are calling a function that expects an argument with no arguments.
2. The return type of `setid()` is `void`. That cannot be used as the RHS of the stream extraction function.

What you need is:

```
std::string id;
cin >> id;
s1.setid(id);
```

---

Suggestion for improvement: Make all the `get` functions `const` member functions.

```
//getters
std::string getid() const;
std::string getunit() const;
int getcredit() const;
int getmark() const;
```

Make sure to update the .cpp file accordingly.

Comment: Thank you sir                                            .